# Raspberry Pi Kernel Panic: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (179, 2)

Tags: compute-module-4, raspberry-pi-imager, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye-64

During my attempt to install the Raspberry Pi 64bit OS on my Compute Module 4 Rev 1.0, I came across this issue.

```
Kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,2)
CPU: 2 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 6.1.21-v8+ #1642
Hardware name: Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 Rev 1.0 (DT)
Call trace:
               dump_backtrace+0x120/0x130
               show_stack+0x20/0x30
               dump_stack_lvl+0x8c/0xb8
               dump_stack+0x18/0x34
               panic+0x1a4/0x37c
               mount_block_root+0x1fc/0x21c
               mount_root+0x1e8/0x21c
               prepare_namepsace+0x134/0x174
               kernel_init_freeable+0x2a0/0x2cc
               kernel_init+0x2c/0x138
               ret_from_fork+0x10/0x20
SMP: stopping secondary CPUs
Kernel Offset: 0x2b66600000 from 0xffffffc008000000
PHYS_OFFSET: 0x0
CPU features: 0x20000,2013c080,0000421b
Memory Limit: none
```

It no longer recognizes my keyboard/mouse anymore either. **This error message persists whether I have a microSD card in or not.** I've tried just about every available related solution: re-imaging the card (with both Etcher and the Raspberry Pi imager), new microSD cards, `sudo fsck`, editing `cmdline.txt`. None produced any difference in the error code or functioning at all. I do not have any important files on the card, I just want my pi to start running again.

Comment: `(179,6)` is the sixth partition on your SDCard. It needs a `fsck -f -y /dev/mmcblk0p6` to get it working again. You can do that with any other Linux system with the broken card in a USB reader. That could be your RPI booted from a second SDCard with RaspiOS Lite booted. `(179,2)` is the second partion (your question isn't clear).

Comment: to clarify, you have a pi without eMMC?

Comment: @Dougie It is (179, 2), I mistyped.

Comment: @JaromandaX it has the 8GB eMMC

Comment: I didn't think it was possible to boot from SD on a CM4 with eMMC

Comment: @JaromandaX you are correct ;-;

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by reinstalling the os via the USB port.